# W3C HTML validation errors: “Stray end tag </head>” and “Start tag <body> seen but an element of the same type was already open”

Tags: html, w3c-validation

Trying to build a website, when I validated it by W3C validator it gave 2 errors:

> Error: Stray end tag head. From line 22, column 1; to line 22, column 7.
>
> Error: Start tag body seen but an element of the same type was already open. From line 24, column 1; to line 24, column 6

Help appreciated to solve the errors.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <title>DOCUFY</title>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

  <div class="header">

    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/d56Pem6.png" alt="BackgroundImage">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="StyleSheet.css">

  </div>

</head>

<body>

  <h1>Världens berättelser framför dig.</h1>

  <p>Se dokumentärer när du vill. Vart du vill. Hur du vill.</p>



  <p class="ex1"><a href="#" class="button1">Logga In</a></p>



  <div class="main" id="section1">
    <h2>Obegränsat</h2>

    <p> Titta via din TV, mobil eller surfplatta,vart och när det passar dig.
      <p>
        <p>Streama online eller ladda ner och se dokumentärerna offline utan internet.
          <p>


            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/svdm3Xo.jpg" alt="Image1" class="image1" style="width:850px">


  </div>

  <div class="main" id="section2">
    <h2>För hela familjen</h2>
    <p> Som medlem kan alla i din familj kan välja fritt inom sina egna intresseområden.
      <p>
        <p> Välj vad just ni känner för att se.
          <p>

            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/gbUVlrE.jpg" alt="Image1" class="image1" style="width:850px">



            <p><i class="material-icons">pets</i>
              <a href="https://www.wwf.se/"> Stöd Världsnaturfonden</a>
              <i class="material-icons">pets</i></p>


  </div>

  <div class="main" id="section3">
    <h2>Flera genrer</h2>
    <p> Historia, vetenskap, journalistik inifrån och många mera är tillgängliga.
      <p>
        <p> Docufy sänder de senaste <a href="https://twitter.com/search?q=history&src=typd">samtalsämnena</a> och <a href="https://www.sciencenews.org/">nyheterna</a> inom forskning.
          <p>

            <video width="420" height="340" autoplay muted controls loop>
  <source src="https://i.imgur.com/UgLQqHz.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

            <video width="420" height="340" autoplay muted controls loop>
  <source src="https://i.imgur.com/wChCbcv.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

            <video width="420" height="340" autoplay muted controls loop>
  <source src="https://i.imgur.com/TyOmu7i.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

            <h2>Prova på gratis</h2>
            <p> Ta del av allt genom att skapa ett konto hos oss idag.
              <p>

                <a href="#" class="button2">Skapa Konto</a>

  </div>

  <footer>

    <p>
      <h3>Kontakta Oss</h3>
      <p>

        <p>
          <div class="FooterSubHeading">Docufy AB
            <p>
          </div>
          <p>
            <div class="FooterSubHeading">Dokumentärfilmsvägen 39</div>
            <p>
              <p>
                <div class="FooterSubHeading">007 11 Filmahult </div>
                <p>
                  <p>
                    <div class="FooterSubHeading">Tel: 007 - 11 11 11</div>
                    <p>
                      <p>
                        <div class="FooterSubHeading">Epost:office@docufy.com</div>
                        <p>
  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The header of your page doesn't actually go in the `head` section of your html, welcome to SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  section of your HTML page should only contain information about the page by way of meta, link, style, script tags etc. and not presentational elements such as DIVs.

Try moving your DIV

```
<div class="header">

<img src="https://i.imgur.com/d56Pem6.png" alt="BackgroundImage">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="StyleSheet.css">

</div>
```

outside of the head element and into the body element.

You can leave `<link rel="stylesheet" href="StyleSheet.css">` inside the head.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following tags from `<head>`

```
<div class="header">

    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/d56Pem6.png" alt="BackgroundImage">

</div>
```

You should not use `<div>` and `<img>` tags in the `<head>` because they are not valid and W3 validator will throw.

Use tags which are valid only in `<head>` tag.